# How to remove decimal from purchase revenue value using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Im trying to track the value of a purchase. However in Google Analytics the value of the total revenue that should be for example 1.321,49 is measured as 1,32.

I already tryed using the following custom JS to remove the ",", but without succes. While trying I wondered how I should return this new value in order to measure it? Maybe its not possible to return in as the DLV - ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue variable that I set up in the tag as value??? Would be nice if you could give me an indept instruction, im not realy familiar with JS and GTM to this extend ;)

function() {
var ecommerce_purchase_revenue = {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}};
var ecommerce_purchase_revenue = ecommerce_purchase_revenue.replace(",", "");
return {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}};   }

Here are some images with more information:

[Datalayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXbQi.png)

[Javascript in GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeQEs.png)

[Google Analytics Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdg6l.png)

[GTM variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQprP.png)

[Updated GTM Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7d4f.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this could be happening.

One reason this could be happening is down to the lack of currency being pushed into the data layer with the purchase.

In the UK and US, we would write the value One Thousand and Thirty Two *[pounds|dollars]*, Forty Nine *[cents|pence]* like so:-

> 1,032.49

However, in Europe, you would write the same value with the following formatting:-

> 1.032,49

To resolve the issue, it is simply required that you specify the currency code in the dataLayer object, or alternatively set this as a field in the tag which sends the Enhanced Ecommerce data to Google Analytics.

Google Analytics will automatically pick this up, correctly formatting the value displayed in Analytics.

Once you are pushing the correct currency value; you may also be required to adjust the Currency Displayed As setting in Google Analytics.

This setting can be found by navigating to:

```
Google Analytics console >> 
Admin (cog, bottom left) >> 
View Settings (far right) >> 
"Currency Display As"
```

[image: Google Analytics Currency Display Setting View]

**Option 1:-**

```
    window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'gtm.dom',
        ecommerce: {
        currencyCode: 'EUR', // NOTE: We have now told google to use EUR formatting
    purchase: {
        actionField: {
            id: '5000000038', 
            affiliation: 'redacted',
            order_id: '5000000038', 
            subtotal: '1,321.49', 
            shipping: '0.00', 
            tax: '277.51', 
            total: '1,599.00', 
            revenue: '1,321.49', 
            discount: '0.00', 
            coupon:''
        },
    products: [{}] // ...
```

**Option 2:-**

You can set the currency code as a field in the tag.

Navigate in GTM to 'Fields to Set' (under the 'More Settings' dropdown), and add a new field:

Field name: currencyCode
Value: EUR

If your site provides the facility to pay using multiple currencies, you can also write some logic to detect the user's currency from either the data layer, browser cookies, or another variable to dynamically set the currency too.

There are lots of helpful examples in [Google's Developer reference](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases) which should help shed further light on what's going on.

Another reason could lie in your conversion function.

I have found that your conversion does not affect the original string, rather it returns the original unconverted value (`return {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}};`)

To resolve that particular issue, adjust the function as follows:

```
function () {
    var eRev = {{ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}};
    var dRev = {{DLV}};
    eRev = Number(eRev.replace(/,/g,''));
    ecommerce_purchase_revenue = dRev - eRev; 
    return ecommerce_purchase_revenue;
    // You might need to convert it back to a string
    // if this is the case, use the following return instead:
    // return ecommerce_purchase_revenue.toString();
}
```

It's important we use regex to do our replace in the function, to allow for cases that include multiple comma separation. (e.g. 1,234,234.12).

Best of luck resolving the issue!

Comment: Thanks for the great and fast response. I have tryed the options. Sadly the data is still not filling in the right way. Is it possible that this can take some time to "reset"?

Comment: It sounds like you may also have your view settings in a different currency. 
To adjust this, navigate to your Analytics Console >> Admin (cog, bottom left) >> View Settings (far right)
On this screen, there is an option to set 'Currency Displayed As' 
Once you update this, you should then see the correct value formatting. 
I have updated my answer to include a screenshot of this setting.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along with me. The currency was already set to Euro in the view setting. I tested it again today, but still having the same issue. Seems like something is still going wrong. I have added a new screenshot of the "Updated GTM - Tag" to my original post. Could you take a look at that? Maybe I still overlooked something.

Comment: Thanks for the update, please find an update in my answer.

Comment: The function required for your conversion is:- 
`function () {
    var eRev = {{ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}};
    var dRev = {{DLV}};
    eRev = Number(eRev.replace(/,/g,''));
    ecommerce_purchase_revenue = dRev - eRev; 
    return ecommerce_purchase_revenue;
    // You might need to convert it back to a string
    // if this is the case, use the following return instead:
    // return ecommerce_purchase_revenue.toString();
}`

Comment: Hi @Selderzzz - How did you get along in resolving the currency display and formatting issue? Did the last update suggesting a change to your conversion function make sense?

Comment: Hi @YenCoder, thanks for your reply. Sadly I haven't been able to test your last update yet. Hopefully I will be able to do so next wednesday :) If I understand it correctly I should make a new variable in GTM with the function that you provided?

Comment: Hi @Selderzzz, the function provided replaces the function described in your original question (`function() { var ecommerce_purchase_revenue = {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}}; var ecommerce_purchase_revenue = ecommerce_purchase_revenue.replace(",", ""); return {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}}; }`). Do let me know if you require further support once you return to it!

Comment: I tried to edit the JS variable and publish it, but I got the following message: 
"An unknown variable {name} was found in another variable. Edit the variable and delete the reference to the unknown variable."

Comment: Do both the variables still exist in GTM, `{{ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}}` & `{{DLV}}` ?